# Send image to WCF from Android

Tags: android, wcf

This is my code from android

```
    public class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Uri... params) {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        if (params[0] != null) {
            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getActivity()
                        .getContentResolver().openInputStream(params[0]));
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, out);
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                byte[] sendData = out.toByteArray();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL + "/"
                        + METHODNAME_UPLOAD);
                httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(sendData,
                        "mobile.png");
                MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                        HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                entity.addPart("image", bab);
                httpPost.setEntity(entity);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
//              if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
//                  throw new RuntimeException(
//                          "Failed : HTTP error code : "
//                                  + response.getStatusLine()
//                                          .getStatusCode());
//              } else {
//                  System.out.println("Success");
//              }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And this is my WCF interface code

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string UploadImage(Stream Image);
```

And this is my method,

```
public string UploadImage(Stream Image)
{
    return "Success";
}
```

I am getting status code `415 (Unsupported Media Type)`

I have searched lot in google. Any help will be highly appreciable. Any other solutions also welcome. What I need is, I want to pick a image using `ImagePicker` and send it ti wcf service, From there I will upload to server.

**Note:** **Alternate solution also welcome**

**Update 1**
After @Vaishali answer I have updated my code as follows

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getActivity()
        .getContentResolver().openInputStream(params[0]));
byte[] sendData = getEncoded64ImageStringFromBitmap(bitmap);
ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(sendData,
        "mobile.png");
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
        HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
entity.addPart("mobile", bab);
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL + "/"
        + METHODNAME_UPLOAD);
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
System.out
        .println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
```

And

```
public byte[] getEncoded64ImageStringFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
    byte[] byteFormat = stream.toByteArray();
    // get the base 64 string
    String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, Base64.NO_WRAP);

    return imgString.getBytes();
}
```

Now the status code is `400`

Comment: Try this, Instead of bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, out); you use bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 75, bos);.

Comment: Also check whether is there any restriction for byte size because of that it doesn't accept file if it is bigger than what specified

Comment: may I know what `bos` here?

Comment: It is object of ByteArrayOutputStream

Comment: Again 415 only I am getting..

Comment: Can you send/upload image from browser by calling same webservice?

Comment: Set the http header to Accept:application/json instead content-type: application/json.

Comment: I dont know how to call this method from browser :(

Comment: Have you tried my last comment answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58425/discussion-between-rit-and-gunaseelan).

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got a mismatch in the data the WCF service is expecing (an IO stream) versus what it looks like you're sending (a byte array).

My experience has been that streams are difficult to get right in WCF, so I'd suggest changing your host-side interface to expect a byte array and see what happens.

Comment: I'm not sure what else to suggest, other turning on extra message-level logging and seeing if you can capture what specifically the server doesn't like about the inbound message. Here's a link to message level logging: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm not get the right answer, anyway I'm add the bounty to you.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty ... if you haven't figured it out yet, sorry. I know these things can be frustrating.

Comment: I'm new to WCF service, that's my problem, Anyway I've omitted this concept from my project, Changed design. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

415 is returned by the server when the entity sent in a request (content in a POST or PUT) has an unsupported mediatype.

Make sure you are sending the same media type which server is asking for.

Read this :

http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E415.html

Comment: I know that friend, I don't know how to resolve this, that's I contacted SO. In my question I have added Service method also.

Answer (score 0):

```
  sendData = getEncoded64ImageStringFromBitmap(bitmap); 

  // here u got sendData is in string format .. pass this to  

   entity.addPart("imageNameWhateverUWantToPass", sendData);



 public static byte[] getEncoded64ImageStringFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
    byte[] byteFormat = stream.toByteArray();
    // get the base 64 string
    String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, Base64.NO_WRAP);

    return imgString.getBytes();
 }
```

Comment: now sendData is byte[] so that u can pass in ByteArrayBody(sendData,
                        "mobile.png");

Comment: sorry i make mistake it would be (String, byte[]) in this format

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest that you send a base64 string then from the web service you convert the base64 string to byte[] and save it or get the image